# Additive color overlay

Tags: rendering, color, freestyle

Is there a way to add colors of objects when they are in front of each other from the camera?
(Maybe some freestyle option)

Like for example, a yellow plane moves over a blue Text, instead of disapearing, the Text turns green where they overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Final & Overview:

[image: final]

> This is partial answer. It's solves question but not other possibilities.

You can **Add** or **Mix Diffuse** shader with **Transparent** shader. **Diffuse** should be color you want to have after mix and **Transparent** is a base color. **Text** has just **Diffuse** shader.

**Why partial?**

Well, it will work only with few colors (yellow + red = orange is working too). I don't know why, and I can't find a proper answer, but if you'll want to mix for example red with blue to get magenta it will fail.

Another con of this method is that you'll need to know how colors are mixing and set it manually.

I hope that someone could elaborate about this issue more. It's pretty interesting.