# Make a dashed line where objects overlap

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I would like to configure Blender to somehow render objects with one freestyle line set where the camera has a clear line of sight to them, but then render another freestyle line set for the objects that are blocked from view. For example...

[image]

Even better would be to recolor the overlapping area...

[image]

This question looked interesting, but not exactly what I'm trying to do:[Additive color overlay](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79515/additive-color-overlay)

What is the best way to go about trying to do something like this? I've tried messing around with the QI Range and things like that in the LineSet visibility options, but I'm kind of coming up empty. The actual objects I'm trying to do this with are more complex and have several parts each which I *do not* want revealed in the render process.If I had to I might be able to somehow manually combine them and delete the spare parts, but that seems tedious and I'd love to avoid it if I can.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76109/automatically-draw-hidden-portions-of-paths-with-dashed-lines/

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Duarte! The dashed line portion of my question can be solved using these steps:

1. Create a second Freestyle Line Set (and name it something like HiddenLines)
2. Click on the Hidden toggle
3. Scroll down to Freestyle Line Style and tick the checkbox for Dashed Line
4. Modify the line settings to your liking

[image: Properties panel settings for freestyle lines]

[image: Result of rendering]